# Connect to Firebird database using Python

Tags: python, firebird

I have a database I need to connect to in order to read the tables, but I haven't even been able to connect it. This my first time trying to consume the information inside a Firebird database, so help will be very appreciated.

I found the way to connect to Firebird DB in this link (https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/getting-started.html#quick-start-guide). My system is Win64 and Firebird server is 32. File is local. I followed the steps and I'm getting the following errors:

```
import fdb
con = fdb.connect(dsn=r'C:\route\firebirdDB.FBD', user='***', password='***')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0ba255790319> in <module>
----> 1 con = fdb.connect(dsn=r'C:\route\firebirdDB.FBD', user='***', password='***')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py in connect(dsn, user, password, host, port, database, sql_dialect, role, charset, buffers, force_write, no_reserve, db_key_scope, isolation_level, connection_class, fb_library_name, no_gc, no_db_triggers, no_linger, utf8params)
    798         return dpb
    799 
--> 800     load_api(fb_library_name)
    801     if connection_class is None:
    802         connection_class = Connection

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py in load_api(fb_library_name)
    229     """
    230     if not hasattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'api'):
--> 231         setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'api', ibase.fbclient_API(fb_library_name))
    232         for hook in get_hooks(HOOK_API_LOADED):
    233             hook(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'api'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\ibase.py in __init__(self, fb_library_name)
   1394         if sys.platform in ['win32', 'cygwin', 'os2', 'os2emx']:
   1395             from ctypes import WinDLL
-> 1396             fb_library = WinDLL(fb_library_name)
   1397         else:
   1398             fb_library = CDLL(fb_library_name)

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371 
    372         if handle is None:
--> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374         else:
    375             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida
```

Comment: "WinError 193" is the relevant part. "no es una aplicación Win32 válida"!

Comment: 1) "firebirdDB.FBD" really? usually it is .FDB, though it is not related to you error, but would probably be the next error you face. 2) translate the error text to English 3) make sure that your python engine executable has the same processor architecture as the fbclient.dll you selected for loading. It seems you try to load Win64 DLL into Win32 process or vice versa.

Comment: Make sure you have a Firebird client library (fbclient) installed matching your Python bitness, or switch to pyfirebirdsql as a driver, as that is pure Python and doesn't require the native client library.